# Site address doesn't work when prefixed with www but works otherwise

Tags: http

Honestly I'm not even sure where to get started. I'm not to savvy when it comes to these things. I've followed a few tutorials and it seemed to work okay.

I've purchased a domain name(www.imgshare.org) via namecheap. I've setup a CNAME record and a A Record and a URL Redirect Record.

So far it seems that http://imgshare.org/ works fine. But if I add www in front as in http://www.imgshare.org it doesn't.

As I said, I'm not too savvy when it comes to this so I'm not sure where the problem lies and me searching google didn't bring up anything relevant.

It's pretty clear that I probably haven't given enough information for you guys to come up with a solution. I'm just looking for some pointing in the right direction here since, as I said, I'm not even sure where to start.

[image: records]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would also need a URL redirect record for www.imgshare.org as that's actually a different process from the DNS lookup. I'm guessing you also would also need to remove the CNAME for parkingpage.namecheap.com.

However, you should also configure your actual server correctly rather than relying on Namecheap.

Comment: The server itself is from a different provider. It's a VPS. I've only purchased the domain name from namecheap.

Comment: However, you're  correct. Removing the extra CNAME works. My bad, thanks a bunch for the help.